# Mass delete action in one step not in loop magento 2

Tags: magento2, massaction

I have custom module with mass delete action feature. how to do mass delete action in one step without loop. Because i got **WARNING | Model LSD method delete() detected in loop** when i check my module in MEQP 2.

Below is the code  used in my module

```
foreach ($collection as $block) 
{

 $block->delete();

}
```

After searching the mass action in the MAGE2 core file they too use the same method.
i refered the following path file is **vendor/magento/module-cms/Controller/Adminhtml/Block/MassDelete.php**

from line no 51 to 53

```
foreach ($collection as $page) 
{
    $page->delete();
}
```

i appreciate any one help on this.

Comment: instead of iterating and deleting on object, use custom My Sql query to delete multiple row with where cause.

Comment: delete on object is only useful  when you want to perform other operation before deleting it.

Comment: @Jjo did you find an answer to this? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Took me a little while to get syntax right on this but you can do a delete from select

Not saying it fits your project but I think it is useful to know

https://github.com/DominicWatts/QuoteCleaner/blob/master/Helper/Cleaner.php

```
    /**
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\ResourceConnection $resource
    ) {
        $this->connection = $resource->getConnection();
        $this->resource = $resource;
    }

    $select = $this->connection
        ->select()
        ->from($this->tableName)
        ->where('ISNULL(customer_id) OR customer_id = 0')
        ->where('updated_at < DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL ? DAY)', 31)
        ->limit(1000);

    $query = $this->connection->deleteFromSelect($select, []);
    $statement = $this->connection->query($query);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
try {
    $categoriesIds = ['1','2','3'];
    // use collection factory object of particular model
    $catgoryObj = $this->_objectManager->get('MageArray\Gallery\Model\ResourceModel\Category\CollectionFactory');

    //apply addFieldToFilter  to get particular  record only  from that collection
    $category = $catgoryObj->create()->addFieldToFilter('category_id', array('in' => $categoriesIds));

    //use walk method for mass delete action
    $category->walk('delete'); 
    $this->messageManager->addSuccess(__('A total of %1 record(s) have been deleted.', count($categoriesIds)));

} catch (\Exception $e) {
    $this->messageManager->addError($e->getMessage());
}
```